# Верстка Flex элементов при скролле по оси X

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть вот такой код. При уменьшении ширины добавил скролл по оси x но элементы текст перепрыгивает на вторую строчку. Как сделать так чтоб текст был в одну строку и не прыгал на вторую при этом скролл работал.   [image: надо чтоб все было в одну строку и скролилось]

[Код табов](https://codepen.io/dmitrij-rog/pen/pMWXap)

```
   <ul class="tabs__caption">
  <li class="tabs__caption--item active">Персональные       тренировки</li>
  <li class="tabs__caption--item">Сплит тренировки</li>
  <li class="tabs__caption--item">Единоборства</li>
  <li class="tabs__caption--item">Групповые программы</li>
  <li class="tabs__caption--item">Прочие услуги</li>
</ul>

    .tabs__caption {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow-x: scroll
}
.tabs__caption--item{
  list-style-type:none; 
  padding:10px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете просто запретить дочерним элементам сжиматься за счет содержимого с помощью свойства `flex-shrink: 0;`

```css
.tabs__caption {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-x: scroll
}
.tabs__caption--item {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs__caption">
    <li class="tabs__caption--item active">Персональные тренировки</li>
    <li class="tabs__caption--item">Сплит тренировки</li>
    <li class="tabs__caption--item">Единоборства</li>
    <li class="tabs__caption--item">Групповые программы</li>
    <li class="tabs__caption--item">Прочие услуги</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: То что нужно ! Спасибо ! Я  пробовал flex-shrink: 0  но  добавлял его к родительскому элементу...  =)